# getting base address from an exe c++

Tags: c++, winapi, openprocess

I tried to get the base starting address from this exe with openprocess, but I keep crashing when I run the code and I don't really see anything wrong with it.

```
HMODULE GetModule(HANDLE han)
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    int i;
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    char szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = "Minesweeper.exe";
    EnumProcessModules(han, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded);
    for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
    {
        TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileNameEx(han, hMods[i], szProcessName, sizeof(szModName));
        //printf(TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i]);
        if (szModName == szProcessName)
        {
            cout << "FOUND" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question should probably have some Windows-specific tags but I don't know which ones would apply.

Comment: `GetModuleFileNameEx`'s last parameter is measured in characters, not bytes, so you shouldn't use `sizeof` for that.  On a Unicode build this could cause a crash.

Comment: Im using multi-byte project, also I did printf that i commented out and I got some addresses but I crashed after I printed them all.

Comment: Also, you never write to `szModName` (`GetModuleFileName` third and fourth parameters use different variables), and you can't compare C-style strings with `==`, you need `strcmp`.

Comment: looks like it got found a billion times http://i.imgur.com/YYeOmwM.png

Comment: Remember `strcmp` returns ZERO for a match and non-zero otherwise.  Also, you might need a substring match, not equality?

Comment: if I want the base address for Minesweeper.exe how would I specifically sort out Minesweeper.exe instead of all these other modals.

Comment: @JhonBrian *Im using multi-byte project* -- But you're using `TCHAR`, therefore you *should* be writing the correct code w.r.t the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- You are using `TCHAR`, but not using `TCHAR` consistently.
- You're using `==` instead of the correct string comparison function.
- The call to `GetModuleFileNameEx` uses the wrong array.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code, with corrections (not tested, but has most if not all of the issues with the code addressed):

```
HMODULE GetModule(HANDLE han)
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    int i;
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = _T("Minesweeper.exe");
    EnumProcessModules(han, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded);
    for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
    {
        TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileNameEx(han, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        if ( _tcscmp(szModName,szProcessName) == 0)
        {
            cout << "FOUND" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `_T()` macro is used to represent string literals.  Since Microsoft has two character-set build types, and you're using `TCHAR`, you should have the rest of your strings be `TCHAR` compatible.  Using straight up `char`, and relying on the character-set build type to save you from a compiler or runtime error is not the way to write the code.

In addition, the `sizeof` in the call to `GetModuleFileNameEx` must be divided by `sizeof(TCHAR)` to be correct.

Also, to address the string comparison, the [_tcscmp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) function is used.  This function will be correct regardless of the character-set build type.

Comment: Still Crashes with this function

Comment: Runs fine for me, no crash. However, the output from `GetModuleFileNameEx()` is a fully qualified path and filename, so you would have to use something like `PathFindFileName(szModName)` to truncate it down to just the filename before then comparing it to `szProcessName`.

Comment: @JhonBrian You need to use the debugger to tell us which line this crashes on.   That would have gone a long way in helping you write the function correctly and / or identify the issue you are having.  Given that, what I wrote are the obvious corrections you needed to make, as your original post was clearly wrong.